# Can not pass tag attribute arguments?(React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parameters, state

I want to get the name attribute of the tag in console.log("mylocation") and console.log

Currently, it is undefined.

### How can i do?

Code

```
class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        category: "myhome"
      };
      this.changeCategory = this.changeCategory.bind(this);
    }

    changeCategory (e, {name}) {
      console.log(name);
      this.setState({
        category: this.state.name
    });
      console.log(name);
    } 
    render() {
      return(
        <div className="app">
          <div
             name = "myhome"
             onClick = {this.changeCategory}
          >
            HiHi
          </div>
          <div
              name = "mylocation"
              onClick = {this.changeCategory}
          >
           myLocation
          </div>
        </div>
      );
     }
    }

    export default App;
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.app'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and welcome to StackOverflow!

The `name` attribute of the clicked element is available through the event object passed to the event handler. That object has a property called `target`, which is the DOM-node you clicked. It's through this node you can get the `name` attribute.

In other words, your change handler should look like this:

```
changeCategory(e) {
  console.log(e.target.name);
  this.setState({ category: e.target.name });
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: No problem :) If this fixed your problem, please mark the answer as accepted, so that future readers of this question can resolve their issue as well.